# What is the difference between these two protection circuits?

Tags: diodes, protection

I have seen both protection circuits used in various designs. The first just back to back diodes clamping a line, the other clamping the line to the system voltage rails.

Whats the difference between these to protection circuits? and what are the pros and cons of using each?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSxQ9M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKbQz2.png)</sup>

Comment: Sources? Are you sure that the second circuit did not use Zener diodes instead?

Comment: Although they are often depicted differently, I assume they are meant to be transient-voltage-suppression diodes.

Comment: The second one seems to be meant a TVS and I see that depiction in power lines. The first one I see in high speed signal protection devices' schematics.

Comment: In these applications they don't put much care on  which symbol is used for which diode type.

Comment: The differences are huge and you can work that out for yourself: Just imagine the Vi being > V+ or < V- and you will see the difference especially if you follow where the current flows.

Comment: Pros: the first one works. Cons: the 2nd one doesn't work.